# Multiple foreign key to single primary key relational database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, constraints

I have this problem where upon updating a foreign key constraint goes missing.
I'm attaching 3 tables.

University Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[University] (
[UniversityId] INT           NOT NULL,
[Location]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_University] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UniversityId] ASC));
```

Student Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
[StudentId] INT           NOT NULL,
[Name]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[UniID]     INT           NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [Uni_FK] FOREIGN KEY ([UniID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[University] ([UniversityId]) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

UniversityManager Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UniversityManager] (
[Id]    INT NOT NULL,
[UnId]  INT NOT NULL,
[StdId] INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_UniversityManager] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [University_FK] FOREIGN KEY ([UnId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[University] ([UniversityId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
***CONSTRAINT [Student_FK] FOREIGN KEY ([StdId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Student] ([StudentId]) ON DELETE CASCADE***);
```

Whenever I update my database, that Student_FK is not updated and goes missing once I reopen the universitymanager table definition.

What I've noticed is the second FK in universitymanager is not updated when I switched between them.

Update button.

[image]

Comment: When you say "Whenever I update my database" how exactly are you updating the database? Are you running a script or using SQL Management studio some how?

Comment: In Visual Studio there is an "update" button when we create a tables ?
Hy, I've updated the post with an image. I hope it clarifies the confusion.

Comment: It might just be that using the gui you don't have the control of, in what order the tables are defined. The SQL scripts you show look good. Why not abandon the GUI editor and just use the sql scripts.

Comment: Hy Chris,
Thank you for your suggestion. I tried building directly from SSMS and using scripts. I still get that error but atleast it shows me what the error is and what to do.
The error:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Stdnt_FK' on table 'UniversityManager' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.